# how to replace a string with a value in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There are data from csv file using read_csv(). Now they are pandas data frames. They may be like the following.

```
1     2 11    
inf   2  1
1   inf  3
```

I used the code:

```
df = df.replace('inf', 1000000)
```

or

```
df.replace('inf', 1000000, inplace=True)
```

So they can not replace inf string with a scalar 1000000.

How to replace inf with 1000000?

Comment: Are there finite values larger than 1000000? I am asking because that might imply there are better solutions than the replace you are trying to do.

Comment: so the inf just means infinity. for handling conveniently, choose a number for example 1000000 to replace inf string. there are not values large than 1000000.

Comment: I know what it means. I am asking whether there is a number larger than "1000000" in your dataframe. If not, replace is a poor choice because you can use faster cython functions. See my answer for performance timings. Regardless of whether 1000000 is the largest number in your array or not, there are better alternatives to replace.

Comment: yes, there is not a number larger than 1000000 in the data frame. so choose 1000000.

Comment: Okay, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275181/4909087), all the solutions there are valid. If it was useful, please let me know.

Comment: yes, it was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.inf`, because `'inf'` is string representation of `inf`:

```
print (df)
          a         b   c
0  1.000000  2.000000  11
1       inf  2.000000   1
2  1.000000       inf   3

df = df.replace(np.inf, 1000000)

print (df)
           a          b   c
0        1.0        2.0  11
1  1000000.0        2.0   1
2        1.0  1000000.0   3
```

Comment: is inf a key word in numpy?

Comment: @LYY - It is constant, check [link](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html)

Comment: @LYY replace works but you can probably do better. Are you trying to change "inf" to another smaller, maximum value in your dataframe?

Comment: so the inf string in data just means a very large number. so replacing it with a larger number value would be the choice.

Comment: inf means infinity.

Comment: @LYY I understand. Let us not disturb jezrael with these notifications, so reply under your question or my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `df.clip_upper` if establishing an upper bound:

```
df.clip_upper(1000000)

           a          b     c
0        1.0        2.0  11.0
1  1000000.0        2.0   1.0
2        1.0  1000000.0   3.0
```

---

Otherwise, you can use `np.isfinite` and set values:

```
df.where(np.isfinite(df), 1000000)
# df.mask(~np.isfinite(df), 1000000)

           a          b   c
0        1.0        2.0  11
1  1000000.0        2.0   1
2        1.0  1000000.0   3
```

If NaNs should not be affected, use

```
df.where(np.isfinite(df) | np.isnan(df), 1000000)

           a          b   c
0        1.0        2.0  11
1  1000000.0        2.0   1
2        1.0  1000000.0   3
```

You can also do this with `isin`:

```
df.where(~df.isin([np.inf]), 1000000)
# df.where(~np.isin(df, np.inf), 1000000)
# df.mask(df.isin([np.inf]), 1000000)

           a          b   c
0        1.0        2.0  11
1  1000000.0        2.0   1
2        1.0  1000000.0   3
```

---

There is an in-place version of the above using `np.where`:

```
df[:] = np.where(np.isin(df, np.inf), 10000000, df)
```

Or,

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.isin(df, np.inf), 10000000, df), 
             index=df.index, 
             columns=df.columns)

           a          b   c
0        1.0        2.0  11
1  1000000.0        2.0   1
2        1.0  1000000.0   3
```

---

**Performance**

```
df_ = df.copy()
df = pd.concat([df_] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.replace(np.inf, 1000000)
%timeit df.where(np.isfinite(df) | np.isnan(df), 1000000)
%timeit df.where(np.isfinite(df), 1000000)
%timeit df.clip_upper(1000000)

9.44 ms ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.26 ms ± 38.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.37 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
605 µs ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```